# Using GCC extensions with code compiled with clang?

Tags: c, gcc

I have a two questions regarding GCC extensions

1. If I compile a library using GCC attributes/extensions, will they work even if I link them to a program compiled with for example `clang`?
2. Should function attributes/extensions be declared in the function declaration or prototype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If the attributes/extensions only affect code generation and not interfaces, it should work.
2. Depends on the attribute.
   E.g., attributes such as `pure`, `const`, or `nonnull`, are no good unless every translation unit that uses the functions can see them—you should put them on the prototypes in your header (and use the underscored form, e.g., `__attribute__((__pure__))`).

   On the other hand, attributes affecting code generation or visibility should be on the implementation, or else if your library user decided to make an override of a function provided by your library, including your header would effectively force those attributes on their override.

In any case, if you put an attribute on the declaration, it affects the definition too (assuming the definition sees the declaration—thanks to [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) for the clarification), but definitions can take on additional attributes not present in the declaration(s).

Comment: You said: "if you put an attribute on the declaration, it affects the definition too" — with which I'll agree as long as the definition sees the declaration, which is not always the case (people have been known to code sloppily).  That said, they've got bigger problems if they run into 'declaration not seen by definition' problems.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the extension.

See https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html

> This document describes the language extensions provided by Clang. In
>   addition to the language extensions listed here, Clang aims to support
>   a broad range of GCC extensions. Please see the GCC manual for more
>   information on these extensions.

Comment: I was more wondering if I can compile a library using gcc with attributes, and then have it work with other compilers, since it is already compiled. I was not specifically interested in clang